# Create a plotly bar chart with different colors for each bar

Tags: r, plotly

How can I create a bar chart with each bar colored differently and also add a legend with the name of each bar and the color used (not the name of the color,the color itself).

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `color` argument

```
fig <- plot_ly(
    x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
    y = c(20, 14, 23),
    name = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
    type = "bar", color = c('red', 'blue', 'green')
 )
fig
```

Comment: in the legend I want "giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys" not SF Zoo

Comment: @firmo23 you can change the `name = c('giraffes', 'orangutans', ..`

Comment: what if the numbers of bars is dynamic and so the number of colors? instead of  color = c('red', 'blue', 'green') what should I use?

Comment: @firmo23 is this coming from a shiny input.  Then you may have to select the appropriate input from `input$color` or so